# How to activate setInterval() incase a text control has the focus

Tags: javascript

Actually I have an update enquery into this point .

I have smth like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(doSmth, 10000);
 function doSmth() {
        var result = document.getElementById("fooText").value;
        if (result != "") {            
                    doSmthElse(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I need to activate the interval ,that is fired each 10 seconds, in case only a text control has the focus else do nothing !!

Comment: Use real words, not everyone here has English as their first language.

Comment: @epascarello - maybe Echo is one such person and they're doing the best they can?

Comment: Thanks for the notification.I would take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for you is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(function(){
    var result = $("#fooText").val();
    if (result != "") {            
        // if
    } else {
        // else
    }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the interval on focus of the field, and clear it on blur:

```
var interval;
$(field).focus(function() {
   interval = setInterval(doMsth, 10000);
});

$(field).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

(the `interval` var has to be global)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in 2 ways,

1. Let the timer run and inside the function check if the `activeElement == <text input>`, then execute the rest of the function else return.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      setInterval(doSmth, 5000);

      function doSmth() {
         var resultEl = document.getElementById("fooText");

         if (document.activeElement.id != resultEl.id) { return false; }

         if (resultEl.value != "") {            
           doSmthElse(resultEl.value);
         }           
       }

      function doSmthElse(result) { alert(result);}     
   });
   ```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HyCmt/1/) here

1. Set the timer on focus of the text box and remove the timer onblur of the input box.

   ```
   $('#fooText').focus ( function () {
   timer = setInterval(function() {
       var textVal = $('#fooText').val();
       if (textVal != '') {
           doSmthElse(textVal );
       }
      }, 5000);        
   });

   $('#fooText').blur (function () {
      if (timer != '') clearInterval(timer);
   });
   ```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HyCmt/2/) here